# How Do I Publish My Java Application On Physical Media?

Tags: distribution, java

I have written an application in Java and my goal is to distribute my software on a disc to be sold. I understand that this is a very complex process and am willing to take it on. Any advice or resources are much appreciated.

**How do I provide the user with the JRE required to run my application?** There seem to be 3 main options as far as I have found, in order from most ideal to least:

1. Include the JRE (Or only necessary components of it?) with my software
2. Install the JRE along with my software using my application's installer
3. Notify the user to install Java themselves and provide a download link to do so

Which of these are correct? Where can I learn more about the industry standards for this?

Comment: Precisely which JRE are you proposing to distribute (and to save us work, what license is that JRE released under)?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.